# Website not working after WP update - do not know what to do now

Tags: wordpress

So, Today my Word Press dashboard said it needed updating. So I hit the update button, and I also updated two plug-ins. The plugs updated okay, but now on my website, I get a 500 error.

I DID actually research some previous questions and answers on this site. My hosting company, Hostinger, sent me here.

I read a couple of answers, and did not understand any of the answers or what I should do. I also don't know how to fix my WP plug, because when I try to navigate away from the dashboard page I'm on right now, and try to go to another page, all I get is a blank white screen.

So, my level of handholding here is extreme.

Here is the error message I'm getting....

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   wp_get_active_and_valid_themes() in
>   /home/u216586391/domains/bluesunlimitedradio.com/public_html/wp-settings.php:477
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/u216586391/domains/bluesunlimitedradio.com/public_html/wp-config.php(77):
>   require_once() #1
>   /home/u216586391/domains/bluesunlimitedradio.com/public_html/wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('/home/u21658639...') #2
>   /home/u216586391/domains/bluesunlimitedradio.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34):
>   require_once('/home/u21658639...') #3
>   /home/u216586391/domains/bluesunlimitedradio.com/public_html/wp-admin/update-core.php(10):
>   require_once('/home/u21658639...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   /home/u216586391/domains/bluesunlimitedradio.com/public_html/wp-settings.php
>   on line 477

Comment: your theme may be deactivated.activate again

Comment: Can you tell me how I would do that? Because.... I cannot navigate in WP at all. If I try to navigate away from the page I'm on right now in WP, I get a blank white screen

Comment: it's more likely update has been corrupted.so some files are missing.here is more  details https://www.sitelock.com/blog/2018/03/what-to-do-when-an-update-breaks-your-site/

Comment: Try downloading the [latest Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/download/) and overwriting your existing files, except for `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Okay. I'm at File Manager utility at my host company's website, and reading that article, I don't see a file called "maintenance" there

Comment: If I overwrite the existing files, won't that wipe out all my content too?

Comment: Can you have access via FTP?

Comment: @Steve not really content is in the database and upload folder + config file

Comment: @Steve in the article white screen of death https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update
just do a manual update but before you begin take a backup database + site

Comment: @awran5 - Hostinger has a File Manager utility, and I can get in there and see my files.

Comment: A tech advisor at my hosting company is going to try to change my WP theme for me.... because I cannot navigate at all in WP.... all I get is an error code. Then I guess I can see if my current chosen theme needs updating, or if deactivating it and reactivating it again will work.

Comment: @Steve In your main WordPress folder, just fine a file called `.maintenance` and delete it.

Comment: Oh, I'm a bit late i didn't read all the comments. just let us know if you need more help.

Comment: So..... the tech advisor has restored my website to a previous version.... and for the time being has asked that I NOT do any updates! I'm pleased it's working again, but not sure what I should do going into the future. I guess I'll leave it as is for now....

Comment: @awran5 - I'm sorry.... I looked, but I did not see any file with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly deactivate your theme by renaming it from server and see if it works then it must be your theme problem. Do (WP_DEBUG, true) in wp-config.php in other cases then tell us about the issues